# htaccess - skip first folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, multilingual

If you have a multilingual site like this:

> example.com/en/some-folder/some-file
>
> example.com/ru/some-folder/some-file
>
> example.com/et/some-folder/some-file

Would it be possible to catch the "ru","en" and "et" into a PHP variable like $lang, and, at the same time, have a directory that looks like this using only htaccess?

> htdocs/some-folder/some-file.php

Instead of:

> htdocs/en/some-folder/some-file.php
>
> htdocs/ru/some-folder/some-file.php
>
> htdocs/et/some-folder/some-file.php

---

I want to be able to not have to re-create all folders and files for each of the languages. But I also want to catch the language in the URL into a variable, and and ignore it as if it does not exist.

Comment: Are these physical folders or virtual? as you could copy another `.htaccess` in the folder & define new rules.

Comment: The en, ru and et are virtual. And all the rest are physical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(en|ru|et)(/.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Rewrite `example.com/en/some-folder/some-file.php` to `example.com/some-folder/some-file.php?lang=en`

Comment: This was such a simple task. I guess i misunderstood rewrite rules and how they work. Thank you so much. Hope other people will find my question and use this simple answer too.