# htaccess - Skip first folder and pass as variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am changing a site into a multilingual site:

> example.com/en/view-item/sku/
>
> example.com/es/view-item/sku/
>
> example.com/de/view-item/sku/

And need to pass the /fr/ part as a variable.

This questions gave a very good answer: [htaccess - skip first folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585428/htaccess-skip-first-folder)

However, in my htaccess file, I also have other rules, for example:

> RewriteRule view-item/([^/.]+)/?$ /shop/view.php?productcode=$1
>
> RewriteRule product-category/([^/.]+)/?$ /shop/products.php?selectedcat=$1

The problem is, that using...

> RewriteRule ^(en|fr|es|de|nl|it)(/.*)$ $2?language=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

...works when a path is not edited by htaccess, for example:

> www.example.com/fr/shop/view.php?productcode=abc123

this adds the language variable on ok.

But for

> www.example.com/fr/view-item/sku/

It does not work, as the htaccess is altering this again. I guess after it has accounted for the /fr/ the url will look like this:

> www.example.com/fr/view-item/sku/

to

> www.example.com/view-item/sku/?language=fr

My knowledge of htaccess isnt go enough to know what code to use to pass the language variable on again.

I have also tried...

> RewriteRule ^(en|fr|es|de|nl|it)(/.*)$ $2/$1/ [NC,L,QSA]
>
> RewriteRule view-item/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /shop/view.php?productcode=$1&language=$2

This works, but wont work for these urls...

> www.example.com/fr/
>
> www.example.com/fr/shop/view.php?productcode=abc123

I assume the very first example will work, if I can pass on the ?language=$1 when editing the /view-item/ folder later.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a work-around for this, by basically putting the above in a different order:

> RewriteRule ^(en|fr|es|de|nl|it)/view-item/([^/.]+)(/.*)$ /$1/shop/view.php?productcode=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
>
> RewriteRule view-item/([^/.]+)(/.*)$ /shop/view.php?productcode=$1
>
> RewriteRule ^(en|fr|es|de|nl|it)(/.*)$ $2?language=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

Although this isnt what my original question was needing exactly, it works fo thought I would post this here. If anyone has any better solutions, please post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en|fr|es|de|nl|it)(/.*)$ $2?language=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^view-item/([^/.]+)/?$ /shop/view.php?productcode=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^product-category/([^/.]+)/?$ /shop/products.php?selectedcat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```